Ubuntu update error not enough space on boot disc. sudo apt autoremove, does not work!
In terminal I get this error listed below when I tried (sudo apt autoremove). This is a single boot system.
user@user-HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~$ sudo apt  autoremove
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-5.15.0-105-generic (5.15.0-105.115) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.15.0-105-generic (5.15.0-105.115) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-105-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
zstd: error 25 : Write error : No space left on device (cannot write compressed block) 
E: mkinitramfs failure zstd -q -1 -T0 25
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-105-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.15.0-105-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.15.0-105-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.15.0-105-generic
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
user@user-HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~$ 


BTW, apt autoremove doesn't "does not work". It removes packages that were installed ONLY to satisfy the requirements of some other package, which has been uninstalled. You don't have any packages that meet that criterion, so it successfully does nothing. What did you expect? Read man apt. Please [edit] your Question  and show us df -h | grep -v "loop".

BTW, Yea thanks Waltinator for being a real Pinner! I don't know much about Ubuntu as I posted. So you don't have to be such a specimen of human waste! There is always someone!                                                                                                                                  Although I would like to thank, Mogens & Hannu for your help!  May Wally will learn or keep his Almighty attitude in Canada...........

Your boot partition seems to be completly filled. You need to at least make some disk space free on that partition.

First check which Kernel you are actually running so that you not delete this kernel by accident. ;-)
You can check your actual kernel by typing:
uname -a

Then you can list all other installed Kernels by typing:
dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'

I would also list the content of the /boot directory with:
cd /boot && ls -ahl
There should be some symlinks targeting some kernels. I would also avoid to delete one of these.

Now you can choose one unused kernel from step 2. Delete it with the command:
sudo dpkg --remove <kernelname>
(Where <kernelname> is the name in the list)

Now you should have some space free to run:
sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove



Do
$ dpkg -l |  grep -E ^ii.*linux-image
and see if you have more than TWO lines printed by that; if yes then do
$ sudo apt purge <full-text-from-second-column>
for those with the lowest numbers.
On top of that, you seem to have at least one COPY EXTRA of lines in the file:at /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54,
to get rid of them, do
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
and remove the second copy, then save the file back with the same name (CTRL-O, Enter).
After that, retry sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
